# Округлить число

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно округлить число , которое в итоге получается

```
$("#total_video span").Math.round(summ);
```

сам код

```
$(function(){
    $('#subscribe_video input:checkbox').on("change", function(){
        var summ = 35.99;
        $('#subscribe_video input:checkbox:checked').each(function(index, element){
            var add = parseInt($(element).val(), 10);
            if(!isNaN(add))
                summ += add;
        });
        $("#total_video span").text(summ);
    })  
});
```

Comment: `var summ = 36; ... $("#total_video span").text(summ);`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var add = parseInt($(element).val(), 10);
> ```

```
var add = +$(element).val();
```

> ```
> $("#total_video span").text(summ);
> ```

```
$("#total_video span").text(Math.round(summ));
```

```
$("#total_video span").text(summ.toFixed(2));
```

---

### И полный код, но по-другому:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#subscribe_video').on("change", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
    $("#total_video span").text(Array.prototype.reduce.call(
      $('#subscribe_video input[type="checkbox"]:checked'),
      function (sum, inp) { return +$(inp).val() + sum; },
      35.99
    ).toFixed(2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="subscribe_video">
  <label><input type=checkbox value="2.65">2.65</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox value="2.99">2.99</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox value="0.004">0.004</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox value="0.006">0.006</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox value="0.004">0.004</label>
  <label><input type=checkbox value="0.004">0.004</label>
</div>
<div id="total_video">Total: <span></span></div>
```

Comment: а как сделать так , чтобы он округлялся до 29.99 , а не до 30

Comment: @kirilly228, сделать `toFixed(2)`

Comment: можете показать куда вставить это ? я просто вообще ничего не понимаю в js\

Comment: @kirilly228, обновил ответ, можешь принимать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну ты хоть добавь пару слов про то, что ты делаешь в ответе. И чем тебе parseInt, кстати, правильно написанный, не нравится :-)

Comment: @Grundy, правильно? Обычно после суммирования целых чисел до двух знаков после запятой не округляют ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy а лучше уж полный код опиши чтоли, а то человеку наврядли ясно что да как (ну или хоть комментарии)

Comment: @Qwertiy, правильно - с указанием основания, а не то, что ему действительно нужен parseInt тут :)

Comment: @alexoander, все, кому не лень, могут опубликовать ещё один ответ. А мне лень...

Comment: @Qwertiy а написать ответ к коменту не лень =) Ну ладно)

Comment: @Grundy, основание не очень то и нужно. Только Опера 12 и старенькие IE будут парсить в восьмеричной системе с ноликом.

Comment: @alexoander, ну комменты хотя бы интересные :)

Comment: Спасибо ) Я такими темпами от вас выучу js

Comment: @alexoander, добавил полный код.

Comment: @kirilly228, добавил альтернативный код.

Comment: @Grundy, и тебя позову :)

Comment: @Qwertiy о , осталось только в 1 строчку это дело запихнуть и обфусцировать =) А так весьма красиво - спасибо за старания) Автор вопроса - ставь галочку=)